# Hide and show on specific row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on image that show and hide the row then it show all sub rows and same as in hide .

Problem clearly define in snippet .

```js
$(".sub").hide();

function diffImage(img) {
  if (img.src.match("minus")) {
    img.src = "http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif";
    // $(img).closest('tr').next('.sub').hide();
    $(".sub").hide();
  } else {
    img.src = "http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_minus.gif";
    // $(img).closest('tr').next('.sub').show();
    $(".sub").show();
  }
}

! function($) {
  $(".sub").hide();
  $(document).on("click", "ul.nav li.parent > a > span.icon", function() {
    // $(this).find('em:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");   
    $(this).show();
    // $('.sub').show();
  });
  $(".sidebar span.icon").find('em:first').addClass("glyphicon-plus");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;" data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/data1.json" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Category Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Product Image</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Seller Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Last Price 1</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Last Price 2</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Seller Rating</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif" class="image1" id="image1" onclick="diffImage(this)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nighty</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" styhttp://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/kanika-pink-satin-nighty/670188371979">
            <object data="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/b/w/Kanika-Pink-Satin-Nighty-SDL202281664-1-f3a2f.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/kanika-pink-satin-nighty/670188371979">
          <p>Kanika Pink Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>r. s. enterprises</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">291</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.9</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif" class="image1" id="image1" onclick="diffImage(this)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nighty</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" styhttp://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>






  </tbody>
</table>
```

I just want when click on main row then only its sub row display or hide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a inline `onclick` event, I prefer binding an `on('click')` event with jQuery.

When the image is clicked, we find its parent (table cell) and that parent (the table row).

Next we select all the table rows until we find a row that doesn't have the `.sub` class. We toggle their view.

```js
$(".sub").hide();


$('.image1').on('click', function() {
  var elem = $(this) ,
      img = elem.attr('src') ,
      parent = $(this).parent().parent();
  
  if( img.match('minus') ) { elem.attr('src', 'http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif' ); }
  else { elem.attr('src', 'http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_minus.gif' ); }
  parent.nextUntil('tr:not(.sub)').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;" data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/data1.json" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Category Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Product Image</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Seller Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Last Price 1</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Last Price 2</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Seller Rating</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif" class="image1" id="image1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nighty</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" styhttp://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/kanika-pink-satin-nighty/670188371979">
            <object data="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/b/w/Kanika-Pink-Satin-Nighty-SDL202281664-1-f3a2f.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/kanika-pink-satin-nighty/670188371979">
          <p>Kanika Pink Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>r. s. enterprises</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">291</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.9</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif" class="image1" id="image1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nighty</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" styhttp://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>






  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like

```js
$(".sub").hide();

function diffImage(img) {
  if (img.src.match("minus")) {
    img.src = "http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif";   
     $(img).closest('tr').nextUntil("tr:not(.sub)").hide();
  } else {
    img.src = "http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_minus.gif";          
     $(img).closest('tr').nextUntil("tr:not(.sub)").show();               
  }
}

! function($) {
  $(".sub").hide();  
  $(".sidebar span.icon").find('em:first').addClass("glyphicon-plus");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;" data-toggle="table" data-url="tables/data1.json" data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Category Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Product Image</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Seller Name</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Last Price 1</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Last Price 2</th>
      <th data-field="state" data-sortable="true">Seller Rating</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent">

      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif" class="image1" id="image1" onclick="diffImage(this)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nighty</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" styhttp://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/kanika-pink-satin-nighty/670188371979">
            <object data="http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/b/w/Kanika-Pink-Satin-Nighty-SDL202281664-1-f3a2f.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/kanika-pink-satin-nighty/670188371979">
          <p>Kanika Pink Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>r. s. enterprises</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">291</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.9</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="parent">

      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif" class="image1" id="image1" onclick="diffImage(this)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>nighty</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" styhttp://www.bls.gov/images/icons/icon_small_plus.gif <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;"></object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="sub" style="display: table-row;">
      <td></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
            <object data="http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/v/c/Masha-Radiant-Combo-of-Purple-SDL825929760-1-4aa36.jpg" type="image/png" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
              <img src="./Snapdeal- Comprice Solution_files/photo_na.jpg" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
            </object>
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/masha-radiant-combo-of-purple/671007367029">
          <p>Masha Purple Satin Nighty</p>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>b boy body wears</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">559</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">updating</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="tab">4.8</p>
      </td>
    </tr>






  </tbody>
</table>
```